# One of my activity is getting error that's why I cant connect to my admin page for unable to getting string from a bundle

Tags: java, android

**As you can see that android studio is showing a problem in
getIntent().getExtras().get("category").toString() and the problem is Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object
android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class AdminAddNewProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private String CategoryName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_add_new_product);
        CategoryName = getIntent().getExtras().get("category").toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, CategoryName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the actual question? What do you specifically want help with? What is the output you are expecting? I would recommend reading [tour], [ask] and [mre] then editing your question to help us help you better

Comment: when ever I'm clicking login as admin. It's showing me the message of welcome admin. But the add category activity is not opening and app is getting crashed alltime.

Comment: Could you edit the question and put that in? I'm not experienced with this problem but if someone can read the question and see all the details in the question and not comments then they might be able to help.

Comment: You are calling ToString() to Null. Just remove ToString(); It will not crash
      
  CategoryName = getIntent().getExtras().get("category");

Toast.makeText(this, CategoryName + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: put data to "category" inside bundle and pass it to intent when you start activity

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli If that is an answer it is better to put it as an answer. That way we can vote up or down depending on if useful or not. Also it means you can get rep.

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli how ?? private String CategoryName  this is also been declared so if we remove tostring() then android studio says an error

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli can you explain through code ???

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: This title isn't making your Question easily searchable.

Comment: The problem isn't calling `toString()` on a null object. It's calling `get()` on a null object of the type `Bundle`, so it's `getExtras()` that returns null. We should see the Activity that's starting `AdminAddNewProductActivity` and should put in the intent extra.

Answer (score 0):

You were calling toString() method to Null object. Simply remove the Method. It will not crash

```
CategoryName = getIntent().getExtras().get("category");
Toast.makeText(this, CategoryName + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Secondly, When you started the activity. You probably didn't pass the data to **"category"** And put this inside bundle Or you didn't pass the bundle to Intent.
In order words, Intent Contain Bundle and bundle contain your data "category";

```
private final String category="SomeCategory";
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putString("category", category);

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdminAddNewProductActivity.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```